# Android can't read blocked numbers anymore

Tags: android, telephony

I know similar question has been asked before,
my code was working before, and now it does not, my app is the default dialer and is also a system app,
the canCurrentUserBlockNumbers(this) returns true, however always an empty cursor is returned now,
any suggestion?
Thank you

```
    if (canCurrentUserBlockNumbers(this))
        Toast.makeText(this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // I see this "OK" Toast
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "KO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(BlockedNumberContract.BlockedNumbers.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{BlockedNumberContract.BlockedNumbers.COLUMN_ID, BlockedNumberContract.BlockedNumbers.COLUMN_ORIGINAL_NUMBER,
                    BlockedNumberContract.BlockedNumbers.COLUMN_E164_NUMBER}, null, null, null);

    TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textviewblockednumbers);
    tv.setText("ciao");

    //int numElements=(c.getColumnCount();

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BlockedNumberContract.BlockedNumbers.COLUMN_ORIGINAL_NUMBER));
            tv.append(name);
            tv.append(",");
            c.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you verify that your app is returned from `TelecomManager.getDefaultDialerPackage()`?

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely returning my app package,
the app can make and receive calls (not fake calls) and send SMS, it's the default dialer,
it's not a new app, I'm just moving to API 29+...

Comment: I can't either add a blocked number anymore, 
I checked on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BlockedNumberContract
there are no deprecated instruction in my code, and no errors are raised during execution, 
it's just returning an empty cursor (c.moveToFirst() returns false)

Comment: Where is this snippet being called from? If an Activity, which part of the lifecycle?

Comment: the list is generated by pressing a button in MainActivity,
I also tried to move to a new Activity in the OnCreate, same odd behavior, canCurrentUserBlockNumbers returns true, my app is the default dialer, but doesn't work and no errors are shown.
maybe a platform dependant issue (?) will try another phone soon,

Comment: Yeah sorry I don't have any more ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update for everyone interested,
with another phone of the same brand (Xiaomi) the cursor is not empty and I can read blocked numbers,
looks like a platform trouble